# How to export spark data frames into excel sheets in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, xlsxwriter

I have an output data frame that I want to export into an excel sheet. So I have used  `xlsxwriter` to export it but when I import it. It shows an error that says that `No module named xlsxwriter`.Is there any alternative library for converting data frame to excel sheets?

Not:- I am using data bricks community pyspark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some helpful information here:
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/getting_started.html

Try to load the package first, if that isn't available, make sure to install the package and restart your notebook.

```
pip install --user xlsxwriter

import XlsxWriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello world')

workbook.close()
```